# RestSharp unsupported grant type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, access-token, restsharp

Trying to query `/token` on my Web API using RestSharp.

In Fiddler I can compose the query and it executes no problem by:
1. Set Method to `POST`
2. Add a header: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
3. Set Body to: username=username&password=pass&grant_type=password

Trying to mimic this in RestSharp:

```
RestClient tokenClient = new RestClient();
tokenClient.BaseUrl = new Uri(GlobalSettings.WebApiTokenUrl);
RestRequest req = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
req.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

//req.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "username", Value = User.Identity.Name, Type = ParameterType.RequestBody, ContentType= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
//req.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "password", Value = User.Identity.Name, Type = ParameterType.RequestBody, ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
//req.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "grant_type", Value = "password", Type = ParameterType.RequestBody, ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
//req.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "response_type", Value = "token", Type = ParameterType.RequestBody, ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
req.AddParameter(new Parameter() { Name = "username", Value = User.Identity.Name, Type = ParameterType.RequestBody, ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
req.AddParameter(new Parameter() { Name = "password", Value = User.Identity.Name, Type = ParameterType.RequestBody, ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
req.AddParameter(new Parameter() { Name = "grant_type", Value = "password", Type = ParameterType.RequestBody, ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
//req.AddParameter(new Parameter() { Name = "response_type", Value = "token", Type = ParameterType.RequestBody });


IRestResponse response = tokenClient.Execute(req);

var content = response.Content;
// I get: {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?
Also why is there a ContentType parameter in the `Paramter` object?  I thought the ContentType should be set in the header? (I also tried removing ContentType from the parameter)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this works.

```
     request.AddParameter("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
     string encodedBody = string.Format("username={0}&password= {1}&grant_type={2}", User.Identity.Name, User.Identity.Name,password);
     request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", encodedBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Refer to this post.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23295/unsupported-grant-type-error-when-trying-to-authenticate